# Visual Studio C++ and Linux

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Long time I was doing dev in Visual Studio, now I have to switch into Linux environment and continue my work there. There are no problem switching to Linux, but I really miss VS 2010. At this stage there are analogs in the world which could be VS competitor.

Question: Is it possible to continue development on Windows under VS2010, and how problematic is migration to Linux afterwards? Do you I need to use some specific and common technologies to avoid problems in future?

Thanks!

Comment: "there are analogs in the world which could be VS competitor"... Right, so why don't you use one of them?

Answer (score 6):

I found Netbeans really good. Note that my case is just opposite, I have always coded on linux/g++ & now I am on Windows. I just installed cygwin and then g++/gcc compilers and on top for an editor I again installed Netbeans on Windows. Just love it. So try out Netbeans on Linux, I hope you would love it.

This does not answer your question & I am sorry to say this but please dont let tools dominate you. Consider tools as your slaves. Just try out writing good algorithms and then converting them to elegant code (in a language that does that task best be it Java, C++, Python or Erlang etc.) on a given operating system/compiler. IDE's/OS/Compilers would always change for better but what always remains is designing great Algorithms and writing beautiful code.

Comment: +1 for the part starting with "Consider tools as your slaves".

Comment: +1, and the point of them making you use linux in school (I assume he's doing this because of uni) is so that you are not dependent on these kind of tools.

Answer (score 1):

According to [WineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=892) VS2010 under Wine is garbage.

On the other hand, developing under VS2010 implies very tight integration with development tools under Windows (like linker, profiler, etc.), and assuming you will be developing under Linux with GCC or the likes, it simply makes no sense to use VS2010 there.

For example, there is no sane way to configure the build environment in project properties and make it work with GCC, the two do not speak each other's languages.

I like [Eclipse's CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/), but your mileage may vary.

If you wish to run VS2010 under Windows and compile under Linux, I suggesting having either one of those (preferably Linux) in a VM, with shared folders, or having the files on NFS, so that you can do your compilation in parallel, all the time, just to make sure you identify problems rapidly. **Editing the files, per se, is perfectly ok this way.**

Sooner or later, you will need to profile your code, to debug your code, etc. **under Linux**, and then you will have to learn Linux-based tools anyway.

Comment: "it simply makes no sense to use VS2010 there." I disagree. VS is a great tool.

Comment: I'm not dissing VS2010 completely, but under the given circumstances. I contend it is much better in the long run to learn an alternative, Linux-compatible IDE which has integration with Linux-based tools (think of debugging in an IDE for example), in this situation.

Comment: Nothing, if you're running it under Windows. But if you depend on a library available only under Linux, and need to profile and debug your code... then VS2010 is useless for you. That's my whole point.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Because the Visual Studio profiler can't measure the performance of code running on Linux!

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: and the Visual Studio debugger does not help you if your program crashes when running under Linux (but does not do so under Windows).

Answer (score 0):

It's not that difficult if you adhere to C++ rules, and not MSVS rules. Yes, there are extensions and things MSVS won't generate errors or warnings for, but might be rejected by other compilers. You also have to watch out closely for UB. What might seem to work on one platform or compiler, but is actually, UB might crash another.

You can do your development in MSVS as long as you periodically compile and test your code on Linux. For the long run though, I'd suggest getting used to a Linux IDE.

Comment: The usual abbreviation for the Microsoft C++ compiler is VC++ or MSVC, not MSVS.

Answer (score 0):

I use vs 2010 and linux.

I have a perl script that moves the files from my pc unto the linux box for testing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Visual Studio option. Microsoft has released Visual Studio Code for Windows, Linux (in two different bitness 32 & 64 for some reason), & OSX. This is not like the VS2010-2013 IDE's. It is mostly a full featured editor with built in version control. In this case version control means Git & only Git & must have git. Yes you must have git to install VSC.

It doesn't have anything like the start a new project template wizard, so be prepared for a more bare bones experience. But it does have intellisense, built in debugging with the typical step in/over/out and symbol viewing, etc.

Be warned its language support varies but this being actively updated.

ALSO you must agree to let Microsoft have any crash dumps. If you don't agree then you can't download VSC.

Language Support: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages

Git requirements: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/versioncontrol

Actual Download: https://code.visualstudio.com/Download